# What is a "Genuine Geraldo interviewee"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, con-air

Here is the scene in Con-Air:

Guard Falzon says:

> Well, welcome aboard. My, my; as I look around I see a lot of celebrities among us. I see eleven Current Affairs, two Hard Copies and a genuine Geraldo interviewee."

1. What is current affair?
2. What is hard copy?
3. What does he mean by "Geraldo interviewee"?

My understanding is this is kind of a joke, like "Genuinely interviewing with Geraldo is a crime too, just like the first two." And Geraldo is an infamous reporter. Is that correct?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[A Current Affair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Current_Affair_(American_TV_program)) and [Hard Copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_Copy) were television tabloid news shows popular in the late 1980's and through the 1990's. Hard Copy in particular was known for its gratuitous violence and questionable material.

[Geraldo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geraldo_(talk_show)) was a similar show starring [Geraldo Rivera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geraldo_Rivera) but geared toward a tabloid talk show format. One of the people being transferred was one of the people interviewed (the *interviewee*) on that show.

The guard's comments seem to be directed towards the 14 convicts whose stories had been covered on the first two 'news magazine' shows and interviewed on the latter sensationalized 'talk show'.

Comment: Great, thank you. And the word "geniunie" was used only because he is talking "classy" then? @Jeeped

Comment: Yes, I infer some sarcasm in *'a genuine Geraldo interviewee'*.

Comment: @HakanErdogan as part of the natural speech pattern, you'd usually add an intensifier to the third (and final) thing in a list like that.

Comment: Note that like *Hard Copy* and *A Current Affair*, *Geraldo* had a reputation for sordid, questionable material;  see the ["Brawl" section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geraldo_(talk_show)#Brawl) of the linked article.